# Pip not installing the last Django-extra-views version (0.12.0)

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm Using Django 2.1.1 with Python 3.6.

While using the following pip command:

`pip install django-extra-views`

It installs the v.0.11.0 and I don't have the 'Factory' changes, so  I can't use `InlineFormSetFactory`, and `InlineFormSet` does not work and gives the following exception:

> Setting `MediaInline.extra` at the class level is now deprecated. Set `MediaInline.factory_kwargs` instead.

I tried uninstalling that version and then installing using the following command:

`pip install -e git://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views.git#egg=django-extra-views`

But doing this Django does not detect the 'import extra-views', so I tried to delete the `-e` from the command, but it stills installing the 0.11.0 without the changes I need.

I've seen on the changelog that they made the version 0.12.0 with the corresponding solution, but I don't know any way using pip or git to install this version.

I also tried asking on the app's Github 4 days ago but I haven't got any response for now.

Maybe I'm missing something so, if anyone could please help me installing the lastest version I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the [github repo](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views/issues/172) and they answered that they needed to perform a release for that.

Now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views.git
```

should be enough. `#egg=` is for `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`.

The command installs version 0.11 because version 0.12 is not yet released. Version 0.12 in the ChangeLog is a documentation for future release.

`import extra-views` must raise `SyntaxError`, the correct syntax is `import extra_views`. If Django still doesn't import it see if your `pip` of the proper version:

```
python --version
pip --version
python -m pip --version
```

> I need to solve this ASAP.

You should avoid such claims at SO, see why: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: The command line you said is giving me an error about `Cannot unpack file`.
But for what I understand I could only get 0.11.0 with it, but I need 0.12.0 to make it work. Is there any way to get 0.12.0 even if it's not released?

About the `ASAP` thanks, I'll edit that.

Comment: *Cannot unpack file* Oops, sorry, have forgotten `git+`. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And do you know any way to install the lastest version even if it's not already released? As I said, The problem with InlineFormSetFactory is what I really need to solve here.

Comment: Installing from a VCS (git in your case) is the only way. Or from nightly tarballs if a project publishes them.